# Not getting source documents from chain in langchain and openAI embeddings

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, openaiembeddings

I'm loading pdfs using langchain.document_loaders:

`loader = DirectoryLoader( './files/', glob='*.pdf', loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)`

then splitted the docs, created the embeddings, stored and loaded them :

```
docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)

...

docsearch = Chroma(persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings ) 
retriever = docsearch.as_retriever( search_kwargs={"k": 5})
docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents( query )
len( docs)
```

I'm getting a correct response but I'm getting 0 source documents.

Comment: It seems like your `retriever` is successfully set up but it's not finding any matching documents for your query. 

Ensure that your documents' embeddings closely align with the queries' embeddings; mismatches could result in no documents being fetched. Try refining the embedding process or adjusting the query parameters to improve matches.

Comment: is it normal or possible to receive a correct answer but no source docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in:

```
docsearch = Chroma(persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings )
```

should be:

```
docsearch = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did set the loader correctly, the below code should work (this is an example, you can change chunk_size or other fields):

```
loader = DirectoryLoader( './files/', glob='*.pdf', loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)
retriever = docsearch.as_retriever( search_kwargs={"k": 5})
docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents( query )
len( docs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first constructor of a `Chroma` object is `collection_name`.
You should pass the `persist_directory` variable to the `persist_directory` constructor argument.
So It will look like this:

```
docsearch = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings)
```